# Pentaho CDE Dashbord: how to export to excel multiple tables into one sheet with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, pentaho, dashboard, pentaho-cde

I have a CDE dashboard with multiple tables using the same column names:
[image]

I need to export to excel all the tables together into one excel sheet. I am using this on my button:

```js
function exportTableData()
{

render_tblRosterTotals.queryState.exportData('xls', null,  {filename:'Roster_totals.xls'});

render_tblClassTotals.queryState.exportData('xls', null,  {filename:'Class_Totals.xls'});

 

}
```

which exports each table as a separate file but need them to both be combined into a single file on a single sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a separate datasource that  combined all the tables data into one query and then used that as the source for the button to export from.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).